# How Multi-stage initialization works in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

How does multi-stage initialization work in omnet++?
I know that the `initialize()` function is triggered by the kernel but  I am not able to understand how the integer variable `stage` gets its value.

Example:

```
void TcpAppBase::initialize(int stage)
 { 
   cSimpleModule::initialize(stage);
   .
   .
   .
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi stage can be defined by numInitStages() function. The default value is one, meaning that if you don't change its value only stage==0 will be executed.
If you change it to 2, for example, you will have to work with stages 0 and 1.
You use this feature only if one wave of initialization is not enough for your purposes.
At the beggining of the simulation the kernnel calls initialize(0) for all modules, then initialize(1) and so on...
In the manual, section, 4.3.3 you will find detailed description of how it works.
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/.

Comment: Yes, your answer is very important.